# Centrar sitios cercanos en mi ubicación

Tags: java, android

tengo este código que lo que hace es mostrarme los sitios cercanos y después me lo centra (al pulsar el botón en concreto) en un sitio cercanos, pero quiero que me lo centre en mi ubicación, pero no se como pasarle ahí en concreto mi ubicación, no se si me he explicado bien, si no decidmelo y trato de hacerlo mejor...

```
private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);

        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));



        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14));


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, dejo el código:

```
case R.id.btVeterinaryFind:
            mMap.clear();
            String veterinary = "veterinario";
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, veterinary);
            dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            dataTransfer[1] = url;

            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lastlocation.getLatitude(), lastlocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Mostrando veterinarios cercanos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

Este es uno de mis botones, en el que le estoy obteniendo mi ubicación, guardándola en una variable y le digo que se centre ahí, así que el funcionamiento es centrarse en mi ubicación y mostrar los puntos cercanos a dicha ubicación.